# How to get another node project root directory from globally installed node package

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have created a tool which generates source code files for the projects in the current working directory and I would like to install it globally `npm -g mypackage` and to store the configuration of this package inside of root folder of each project that uses this tool in `.config.json` file.

My question is how I could get the root path of another project from the node? If this would be not a global package I could do it with `module.parent`. But if it is installed globally than there is no parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a better answer than to look for `package.json` file recursively in parent directories.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg-dir package can be used for this purpose.